# azure kql parse function - unable to parse ? using regex (zero or one time)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to parse this line:

```
01/11/1011 11:11:11: LOG SERVER = 1 URL = /one/one.aspx/ AccountId = 1111 MainId = 1111 UserAgent = Browser = Chrome , Version = 11.0, IsMobile = False, IP = 1.1.1.1 MESSAGE = sample message TRACE = 1
```

using this parse statement:

```
parse-where kind=regex flags=i message with 
timestamp:datetime 
":.*LOG SERVER = " log_server:string 
".*URL = " url:string 
".*AccountId = " account_id:string 
".*MainId = " main_id:string 
".*?UserAgent = " user_agent:string  
",.*Version = " version:string 
",.*IsMobile = " is_mobile:string 
",.*IP = " ip:string 
".*MESSAGE = " event:string 
".*TRACE = " trace:string
```

now the thing is that sometimes I got records that has one "key=value" missing but the order of the rest of the columns remains the same.
to match all kinds of rows I just wanted to add (<name_of_colum>)? for example:
"(,.*Version = )?" version:string
but it fails everytime.

Comment: @Yoni L. can you take a look? seems like a bug

Comment: @Avnera can you take a look? seems like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator)/[parse-where](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsewhereoperator) operators are more useful when you have well formatted inputs - the potentially missing values in this case would make it tricky/impossible to use these operators.
If you control the formatting of the input strings, consider normalizing it to always include all fields and/or add delimiters and quotes where appropriate.
Otherwise, you could use the [extract](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractfunction) function to parse it - the following expression would work even if some lines are missing some fields:

```
| extend 
    timestamp = extract("(.*): .*", 1, message, typeof(datetime)),
    log_server = extract(".*LOG SERVER = ([^\\s]*).*", 1, message),
    url = extract(".*URL = ([^\\s]*).*", 1, message),
    main_id = extract(".*MainId = ([^\\s]*).*", 1, message),
    user_agent = extract(".*UserAgent = ([^,]*).*", 1, message),
    version = extract(".*Version = ([^,]*).*", 1, message),
    is_mobile = extract(".*IsMobile = ([^,]*).*", 1, message),
    ip = extract(".*IP = ([^\\s]*).*", 1, message),
    event = iff(message has "TRACE", extract(".*MESSAGE = (.*) TRACE.*", 1, message), extract(".*MESSAGE = (.*)", 1, message)),
    trace = extract(".*TRACE = (.*)", 1, message)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the solution but I preferred using the flexibility with regex instead. I still hope the bug will get fixed.

Comment: I don't think there's a bug here (please correct me if I've missed anything) – 
In the following simplified example 
datatable(message: string) [
    "LOG SERVER = 1 URL = /one/one.aspx/",
    "LOG SERVER = 1"
]
| parse-where kind=regex flags=i message with "(LOG SERVER = )?" log_server "(URL = )?" url

The arguments are internally converted to the regex **“(LOG SERVER =)?(.*)(URL = )?(.*)”** 
Since the provided regex expressions are in parenthesis, the first “.*” (representing log_server) will consume everything after itself – this is not what we want to achieve, but it is not a bug…